# I need a substitute for ghex

Tags: regex, sed, command

When i install **Sublime Text 2** in my system(Debian) i need to use `ghex` to find the address `0x590ADC` with Edit->Goto Byte. After that, i need replace the number `33` for `32`. All this to solve a problem with backspace key.

So, i would like to know if there is other way to do that without using `ghex`, i would like to do that using command line(sed maybe) because i use a bashscript to install all my system, including softwares like **Sublime Text 2**.

Bellow, a `sed` command that replaces all occurrences of `33 42` and replaces for `32 42`.

```
sed 's/\x33\x42/\x32\x42/g' sublime_text
```

I need something like above, but in a specific address, and `42` is not necessary anymore.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and `dd`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function replace {
    [[ $# -eq 4 && -f $1 ]] || return 1
    local FILE=$1 ADDRESS=$2 EXPR=$3 LENGTH=$4
    local BLOCK_SIZE=512
    local BLOCKS=$(( ADDRESS / BLOCK_SIZE ))
    local REM=$(( ADDRESS - (BLOCKS * BLOCK_SIZE) ))
    {
        [[ BLOCKS -gt 0 ]] && dd bs="$BLOCK_SIZE" count="$BLOCKS" status=none
        [[ REM -gt 0 ]] && dd bs=1 count="$REM" status=none
        printf "$EXPR"
        dd bs=1 count="$LENGTH" of=/dev/null status=none
        dd bs="$BLOCK_SIZE" status=none
    } < "$FILE"
}
```

Example data (`hexdump -C` format):

```
00000000  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f  |................|
00000010  10 11 12 13 14                                    |.....|
```

Test:

```
replace data.bin 10 '\xFF\xFF' 2
```

Output:

```
00000000  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 ff ff 0c 0d 0e 0f  |................|
00000010  10 11 12 13 14                                    |.....|
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern match 33 and 33 42 also 
    ~s/\x33(\x42)?/\x32$1/g

Answer (score 0):

`sed` doesn't have byte addressing, but it's easy enough to do this with standard tools.

```
( cut -b1-5835484 file; printf "%c" 50; cut -b5835486- file )>newfile
```

Given enough unique context, it is possible to find an expression which *probably* only matches once in the file (but in the pessimal case, you need the entire file as context) so you can do something like

```
sed 's/\(\x01\xf3\x29\x02\)\x33\(\x42\x29\xea\x44)/\1\x32\2/' file >newfile
```

There are also programmable hex editors which allow you to do this with a simple `sed`-like language with byte addressing.  Or if you have a hexdump program which reads its own input to reconstruct a new file, do something like

```
hexdump file |
sed 's/\(^0x0x590AD0 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. \)33/\132/' |
hexdump -v >newfile
```

Comment: The proper fix, of course, is to switch to Emacs. `<ducks/>`

Comment: A slightly less intrusive fix is to package your hacked Sublime Text in a repo of your own, and install from that.